# Trying to get these outputs counted in separate columns using SQL

Tags: sql

Alright guys,

Trying to count some data from an Access database using SQL and format it in a certain way. The output is supposed to look like this:

Type            NumberSold
Detached        5
Semi-Detached   2
Terrace         1
Link            8

The table headers I need to use for this are PropertyType and SoldUnsold (I only want the ones which have been marked as sold.

So far I've gotten this SQL:

```
SELECT PropertyType
COUNT(*) AS NumberSold,
SUM(PropertyType = 'Detached') AS Detached,
SUM(PropertyType = 'Semi-detached') AS SemiDetached,
SUM(PropertyType = 'Terraced') AS Terraced,
SUM(PropertyType = 'Link') AS Link
FROM SaleProperty 
WHERE SoldUnsold = 'Sold'
```

I feel like I'm on the right track with adding up each individual property type, selecting it from the correct heading in the table. The error I'm getting is to do with the COUNT(*) part which apparently has a missing parameter.

Any help is greatly appreciated! (if more info is needed then it will gladly be provided, haven't asked anything about SQL on here before)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a missing comma after PropertyType and missing `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT PropertyType,
COUNT(*) AS NumberSold,
SUM(PropertyType = 'Detached') AS Detached,
SUM(PropertyType = 'Semi-detached') AS SemiDetached,
SUM(PropertyType = 'Terraced') AS Terraced,
SUM(PropertyType = 'Link') AS Link
FROM SaleProperty 
WHERE SoldUnsold = 'Sold'
GROUP BY PropertyType
```

I prefer the following format:

```
SELECT PropertyType
     , COUNT(*) AS NumberSold
     , SUM(PropertyType = 'Detached') AS Detached
     , SUM(PropertyType = 'Semi-detached') AS SemiDetached
     , SUM(PropertyType = 'Terraced') AS Terraced
     , SUM(PropertyType = 'Link') AS Link
FROM SaleProperty 
WHERE SoldUnsold = 'Sold'
GROUP BY PropertyType
```

As far as syntax goes, that explains your error, as far as desired output it may not line up with what you're after, but some sample data/desired output in your question would make that easier to determine.

Comment: Well, I do feel a fool. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MichaelDelahorne It happens to the best.